# ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext

Tags: google-compute-engine, continuous-deployment

I have just got the release pipeline working with Google's push to deploy on App Engine.

I released that some of my unit tests were failing.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named google.appengine.ext)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/deployment_5175583809994752_1410355681821/tests.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cfc.search.nosqlhelper import set_meeting_date
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/deployment_5175583809994752_1410355681821/cfc/search/nosqlhelper.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cfc.models.event import Event
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/deployment_5175583809994752_1410355681821/cfc/models/event.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.270s
```

I tried to run the following from python REPL in the VM containing Jenkins provisioned automatically via release pipeline in Google Developer Console.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

I got the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

I logged into the VM and noticed that the files are located at for instance:

```
var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/bbc6deda44e4806c5c0e377df6f1109733e382e8531c1c9ed440084d8e98e3fe/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_
appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py
```

How do I se the path universally in the VM ?

Comment: So I can import from google.appengine.ext in the python REPL for the VM. However I am still seeing failed Unit Test with the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Push-To-Deploy Pipelines - Unit tests fail with module import error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029120/google-push-to-deploy-pipelines-unit-tests-fail-with-module-import-error)