# Google Push-To-Deploy Pipelines - Unit tests fail with module import error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, release-management

I get the following error when I try to execute a build on the Google provisioned Jenkins servers in Compute Engine.

```
[deployment_5371449468518400_1411607125060] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson807438832151987098.sh
+ nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named google.appengine.ext)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/deployment_5371449468518400_1411607125060/tests.py", line 9, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.448s
```

I am confident that this is happening because of the following line in my tests.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

Please help.

I am including a [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z0kdZGA_QwaKMfECUR39vcWCl00QuXyIG3pj9Ypcp0k/edit) to a doc which has more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joseph, as the path is not set correctly, please add this to the beginning of your tests.py file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine")
```

Please, don't forget to add this part before trying to import anything from that library as the path wouldn't be configured yet.

In other words:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine")

some other imports
#next import ONLY after the path has been updated to point to the App Engine libraries
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

Comment: Is there any update on this? The above solution did not work for me either.